# HTTP post without redirecting user

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to push data to a form in ASPX, but I dont want to the user to be taken to the post page.

I.e

When a user registers on the site I need to push some data to a form and submit the form withtout the user being redirected.

Sp

Comment: Once the user submits their registration form I need to post some details to another page but I need to do this in the background.

I hopes this makes sense..
Sp

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? That the user submits that data but ends up on the page they started? Or that the user never leaves the page at all?

Comment: The user submits the form and get redirected to a thank you page, i need the thank you page to sumbit data to another page without being redirected from the thank you page.

Comment: Is this page: 1.) part of the same ASP.Net app? 2.) In another ASP.Net app within the same domain? 3.) In another domain altogether?

Comment: Im trying to send some data to a php page that an external company has built for us and they require us to post in this way(I begged them for a webservice!!) It will be on  a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for  [AJAX and ASP.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479042.aspx)?